# Attempt at proving using natural deduction " The intersection of the set of R-equivalence classes on A is empty"

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I've tried to present in a natural deduction style the proof of the proposition

"For any two different R-equivalence classes on A, their intersection is empty".

Please tell me which improvements could be made to make the proof more rigorous, regarding in particular the use of variables and quantifiers.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more rigorous if you used formal definitions for symmetry and transitivity of R.

And the conclusion (line 33) could be stated using a formal logic expression as well, e.g.:

$\forall a \forall b ([a] \not = [b] \to [a] \cap [b] = \emptyset)$

Otherwise, your proof is good ... with one very minor mistake: Line 9 comes from line 5, not 6

Comment: Thanks for taking time to read this! I'll correct according to your comment.

Comment: @Bram28.Does using formal definitions for symmetry and transitivity amount to using the definitions of these properties as premises?

Comment: @EleonoreSaintJames Yes ... if you have those definitions, you can add them as premises

Answer (score 1):

If x in [a] $\cap$ [b], then x ~ a, x ~ b and a ~ b, so [a] = [b].

Comment: @WilliamElliot.That's more elegant, indeed. I however perceive some kind of irony in this laconic answer. +1 nevertheless, as a proof of my magnanimity